# How to get the absolute path of the calling file in a function that's called in PHP?

Tags: php, path

in `file.php`:

```
call()...
```

How to get absolute path of `file.php` inside `call()` ?

Pay attention that `call()` may be defined in another file.

`another.php`:

```
function call(){..}
```

`file.php`:

```
include(path_to_another.php);
call();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

no way except [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

```
function whatever() {
    $t = debug_backtrace();
    echo "called from {$t[0]['file']}";
}
```

Comment: For getting relative paths up to the root, I used `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. With my function `root()`, I can get the `'../../` path to the root easily. @user187291 and your answer got me started; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to James Brooks's answer and Bretticus observation, if you need to get the `basename` of the **calling file** you can do:

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
$file_name = basename($backtrace[0]['file']);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also get the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for the file, like so;

```
basename(__FILE__);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: __FILE__ will only give a reference to the include file, not the file calling it.